# Regex to match everything after a pattern occurrence until the next pattern occurs and so on

Tags: python, regex

I'd like to extract everything that follows a "line break and integer" until the next "line break and integer", where i'd like to capture everything that follows that and so on.
For example for the following string:

```
"\na \n1 b\nc \n2 b\nc \n3 b\nc"
```

I'd like to capture the following groups:

```
["\n1 b\nc ", "\n2 b\nc ", "\n3 b\nc"]
```

This is what i've tried

```
re.findall("\n\d[\s\S]*(?=\n\d)*","\na \n1 b\nc \n2 b\nc \n3 b\nc")
```

But it's not splitting the matches, I think i need to make it "non-greedy" but i'm not sure how.

```
['\n1 b\nc \n2 b\nc \n3 b\nc']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this regex in DOTALL or single line mode:

```
(?s)\n\d.*?(?=\n\d|\Z)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/3ZHiCB/1)

**RegEx Details:**

- `(?s)`: Enable single line mode to allow dot to match line break
- `\n`: Match a line break
- `\d`: Match a digit
- `.*?`: Match 0 or more of any characters (lazy)
- `(?=\n\d|\Z)`: Lookahead to assert that we have either another line break and digit or end of input

**Code:**

```sh
>>> import re
>>> s = "\na \n1 b\nc \n2 b\nc \n3 b\nc"
>>> re.findall(r'(?s)\n\d.*?(?=\n\d|\Z)', s)
['\n1 b\nc ', '\n2 b\nc ', '\n3 b\nc']
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably another way is to match from beginning of line with digits
to next beginning of line with digits.
This will allow for the beginning and and of string.
Group 1 contains the part you're interested in.

`(?m)^\d+([\S\s]+?)(?=^\d|\Z)`

https://regex101.com/r/ctC5KO/1

```
(?m)
^ \d+ 
( [\S\s]+? )     # (1)
(?=
  ^ \d 
| \Z 
)
```